# onBeginContact not dispatched

Tags: phaser-framework

I have refactored my code in order to use states and classes. The code is cleaner but the callback associated to the `onBeginContact` is not called anymore. Without classes, it was working as expected.

In Boot.js:

```
this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
```

In Game.js:

```
this.ship = this.game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'ship');
this.ship.animations.add('propulse', [1, 2, 3]);
this.game.physics.p2.enable(this.ship, false);
this.ship.body.addPolygon({}, 30, 35  ,  0, 35  ,  14, 5);
this.ship.body.onBeginContact.add(this.hitWall, this);
```

`hitWall` is not called. I have tried using a simple function but same issue. If you need more information, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
```

Should be in Game.js too.

Comment: More specifically, the physics system is destroyed whenever game state changes. That is why the physics system needs to be restarted and configured accordingly.